# html2canvas renders the font family incorrectly if the letter combination is "fi"

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I'm trying to generate an image of a `div` tag using `html2canvas` library but it's not working. The font does not rendered correctly if the text containing the combination of letter `fi`.

Please take a look at this screenshot to get the idea:
[image]

Please check my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87svsgc7/20/)

I did a lot of research but unable to come up with a solution.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like it's a known issue with [ligatures](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/838).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fixed it myself by going through [this](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/838) thread. It's a ligatures issue and here's the code to fix it.

```
var el = document.getElementById('myElement');
el.style.fontFeatureSettings = '"liga" 0';
html2canvas(el, options);
```

Here's the working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87svsgc7/24/)

Comment: still facing the same issue